# Disable need for Host Key with Vmware

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox, vmware

In Virtualbox, it auto-switches between host and guest when I change virtual screens in Linux. In Vmware I always need to press the host key combination. Is there any way this could be disabled?

Comment: Have you installed the VMware Tools?  This should allow you to move between the host and the guest.

Comment: No I can, move between host and guest, the problem is it requires an extensive key combination. I'd rather eliminate the need of the host key to do it, like in Virtualbox. And yes, I have VMware Tools.